# How to repair mongodb database on Openshift?

Tags: mongodb, openshift

Accessing my mongodb database on my openshift app has become problematic.  It is now slow and unresponsive. The app is just a small testing and the database is extremely small.

I noticed the unresponsive today after I reorganized the database moved a lot of documents around. I'm just assuming that this caused the problem.

The mongodb docs say there is a repsir option to fix this sort of thing.

```
 Mongod --repair
```

How would you go about doing this on Openshift?

Any other ideas for repairing?

Answer (score 0):

From reading this post it seems that the repair step is run automatically on restart.

https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/mongodb-not-working-since-yesterday